# Online Payments Using Paypal NVP Api

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I am developing a website with online payment.

**Payment is done using Paypal NVP Api.**

There is need of a facility to store customers credit card details(not in database) once they register to Website.There onwards whenever they order these details will be fetched, Customer need not enter their card details for every order.

So is there any facility to create a profile n store credit card details of customer, as it is there for recurring payments?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the idea of paypal, you are not allowed to store the customer credit cart and use them later by your self - if you do that, paypal see its and block your account in no time.

The paypal offer recurring payments, so you only need to initialize correct the paypal options and you have your solution.

Or get permission from visa, or master-cart to have the ability to keep local the credit cart informations. I must say that is very dangerous and if your system is not well protected you put your clients and your business in a big risk to lose the credit cart data and have real problems.

> to store customers credit card details(not in database)

Where to you wish to store it ? in the paper :)?

> Customer need not enter their card details for every order.

This is something that paypal take care of. You do not have to do something about.

Comment: How does Paypal take care of customer not entering card details for every order, if its not recurring payment?

Comment: @DEvika, paypal take care customer data with too many security points and checks.

Comment: So mean to say If we have Merchant Account, we can store our Customers profile with their credit card details and we can use that while order processing.

Can you pls elaborate more on this or any link that I can refer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check Recurly.com 
they are providing support for Paypal and other gateways too.  Plus great API documentation. 
using it and definitely recommend it.  10 out of 10